# Export XML Files from SQL Server 2016 UTF-8 encode without bom

Tags: sql-server, xml, encoding, utf-8, sql-server-2016

As you might now Microsoft finally supports UTF-8 in their SQL Server 2016

Im wondering how can I create an XML file from a stored procedure that is UTF-8 encoded and has no bom.

In the Technical Overview of the SQL Server 2016 it says the following:

> Support for import and export of UTF-8 data
>
> Data stored in a UTF-8 encoded file can now be imported into SQL Server and exported from SQL Server into a UTF-8 encoded file, using BULK INSERT T-SQL command and bcp command line utility. As a part of the import process, the UTF-8 encoded strings are read from the file, and converted and stored as native data types that correspond to the target columns in SQL Server tables. As a part of the export process, data are converted from native data types into UTF-8 encoded strings and written into the file. All native data types are supported except Xml, SqlVariant, Text, NText, and Image.

In my understanding i could now create a UTF-8 file with the following command:

```
declare @command varchar(8000)

set @command = 'bcp "select * from Table" queryout 
"{path}"  -T -t; -c -C65001'

exec xp_cmdshell @command
```

But I dont know how I can create a file from a "FOR XML" Query. Also i dont know whether the resulting file is going to be with a BOM or not.

I could not find any answers after searching with google for half an hour so im trying to find an answer here.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to trip up other applications that will try to read the file? In any case `bcp` isn't an export tool. *Administrators* typically use it from the command line. Calling it inside a stored procedure is a serious problem, not least because it requires elevated priviledges. Just use the *appropriate* tool for this job - SSIS

Comment: Well normally i would use the following command: 
execute sp_OAMethod
but as i read in the technical Overview that only BULK INSERT and BCP support writing UTF-8 Files I decided to try it with bcp

Comment: even worse. Not only does it require elevation, it's plain-old-ancient. Why aren't you using the *appropriate* tools? No documentation or article mentions `BULK INSERT` or BCP for that purpose. *All* of them mention the Export Wizard, which is a front-end to SSIS. SSIS has an entire section to itself in the documenation. What are you trying to do???

Comment: I have a stored procedure that should be able to export an xml file into the Filesystem from a "FOR XML" Query. This file should be UTF-8 without a BOM. This is a SQL Server Agent job that once a day creates XML files from certain tables. A batch file then sends the xml Files to an FTP server for other institutions to use.

Comment: I haven't tried it but I hope SQL Server doesn't use BOMs for UTF-8. BOM for UTF-8 is nonsense. UTF-8 is a byte-wise encoding. So no byte-order issues can arise. BOM is only relevant for UTF-16 and UTF-32, which are word (2-byte) and double word (4 byte) encodings.

Comment: I am exporting xml files from SQL Server 2008 at the moment (converting XML variable to .xml file) and the encoding listed in notepad++ for the resulting file is `utf-8 bom`. I came here to try to find out how to remove the bom, because I agree... it is nonsense to have it on utf-8

Comment: @HighPlainsGrifter The easiest way in my opinion is to use a powershell script. You can execute this from sql directly.
`powershell -Command "$MyFile = [System.Io.File]::ReadAllText('''+@tempFileAndPath+'''); [IO.File]::WriteAllLines('''+@FileAndPath+''', $MyFile)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write a mini tool on my own...

In the following I write `C#`, but this is valid for most higher programming languages:

- C# can call a query which returns XML (`SELECT ... FOR XML ...`) without any problems
- In C# xml from SQL Server is mapped to string.
- C# is able to convert this string to any format you need
- C# can write this to any location it is allowed to write to
- C# can do this timer driven or you might use a job

SQL Server is very limited in writing to the file system. You might use SSIS of course...

If you do this in .Net you might even inlcude this as assembly into the database and call it with a T-SQL-statement.

Comment: That actually sounds quite nice. But i've heard about compatibility issues when moving to a new SQL Server version. Is that really such a big issue?

Comment: I don't know... To be honest, I would not integrate this as assembly but rather deploy this as a side tool. This allows to have customer specific configurations (XML file?) and will work in the context of the user, while the rights for the file system **within** SQL-Server are bound to a SQL-Server user and the machine where the server is running.

Comment: I will probably integrate an assembly into the SQL Server since I would like to have most of the logic in a stored procedure. I would only encapsulate the filewriting part into an assembly and call it from my stored procedure. But anyway thanks for your answer. It helped a lot.